# Datatables - Can't filter columns using sub items

Tags: jquery, datatables, metronic

I want to filter rows using "type" column value. it's coming from sub object named article. I can't direcly access that property. I need to use array key like `row.articles.type`

I'm able to filter using status which is depends on is_suspend column, I can easly access is_suspend saying that `row.is_suspended`. But it comes to sub object values, it doesn't filter..

one item look like;

```
{
id: 7,
user_id: 11,
article_id: 216,
content: "Rerum velit soluta quos provident corporis eum dolores. Dolorem ex deleniti quisquam. Voluptas eum sint itaque quibusdam vel. Non sit alias cumque doloribus aut.",
created_at: "2018-09-14 21:22:53",
updated_at: "2018-09-14 21:22:53",
is_suspend: 0,
user: {
       id: 11,
       name: "Mayra Rau",
       username: "edgar.schmeler",
       email: "leuschke.kraig@example.org",
       created_at: "2018-09-11 00:15:47",
       updated_at: "2018-09-11 00:15:47",
       suspended_at: null,
       banned_at: null,
       points: "3772"
},
article: {
         id: 216,
         locale: "fr",
         content: "Qui earum repudiandae aliquam et ab aut maxime. Debitis alias voluptatum voluptate ut ut. Repellendus asperiores ut rem aut et voluptates eum. Sed voluptatem repellat maiores. Dolores commodi laboriosam voluptatem deserunt reprehenderit.",
         articleable_id: 72,
         articleable_type: "App\Models\Cpu",
         type: "Cpu",
         articleable: {
                      id: 72,
                      title: "AMD A4-9120",
                      slug: "amd-a4-9120"
                      }
         }
},
```

**Field section**

```
{
    field: "type",
    title: "Type",
    width: 70,

    template: function (row) {
    var status = {
        Cpu: {'title': 'CPU', 'class': 'm-badge--info'},
        Gpu: {'title': 'GPU', 'class': ' m-badge--default'},
        Mb: {'title': 'MB', 'class': ' m-badge--warning'},
    };
    return '<span class="m-badge '+status[row.article.type].class+' m-badge--wide">'+status[row.article.type].title+'</span>';
}

},
```

**Filter section**

```
$('#m_form_type').on('change', function () {
    datatable.search($(this).val(), 'type');
}).val(typeof query.Type !== 'undefined' ? query.Type : '');
```

Comment: Would love to have a crack at this but your JSON seems invalid according to jsonlint. Perhaps work up a JSFiddle (or similar)?

Comment: @annoyingmouse I just copied items to show. there is no problem with json data, I'm able to get any of them

Comment: I sort of assumed that there wasn't but the copy wasn't for a valid JSON object so I couldn't get to grips with what your issue was if I couldn't examine the data - I was merely trying to be helpful, not criticising. Is you could work up an example it would help...

Comment: @annoyingmouse, I updated my question, I hope it's clear this time. Sorry for that messy question..

Comment: I've not used `template` in DataTables but a render function seems to do what I think you need: http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/vrno3hpe/

Comment: @annoyingmouse template also works too, problem is I can't filter them. Because `type` value coming from sub item and I can't archieve in filter section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180100/discussion-between-annoyingmouse-and-hasan-tingir).